# Can't change price of in-app purchase

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I'm unable to change the price of an in-app purchase. I added initially for testing purposes, but now that I'm submitting the app, I'd like to change it. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to accept the change. Any ideas or should I just wait?

SO has been invaluable in resource in getting feedback from developers from all over who have experienced the same problems I have - especially when it comes to debugging a variety of mystifying aspects of the submission process. What an awesome resource! Conversely, apple is slow to respond, and when they do, it's pretty useless!

Comment: Did you find any solution for the price tier inn  inapp Purchase .I am facing the same problem and not able to find any way.

Comment: I'm exactly having the same issue for a while.

Comment: Possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698734/unable-to-change-the-price-tier-in-the-in-app-purchase Had the same issue and that answer on the link above helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I've just have a look at my iap product, and I can edit the price even if the app is ready for sell. so you could have a re-try, good luck.